# Make sure entire dynamically-generated ul and its lis appear above bottom of page

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamically expanding browse tree.  When the user clicks a dynamically-created li, s/he expands the next UL > LI.  If there is only one selection in the newly-created UL, it automatically forwards to the next level.  When this happens, the items in the 3rd list sometimes display below the bottom of the page.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<ul id="ul-level-one">
    <li id="1">Item one</li>
    <li id="2">Item two</li>
    <li id="3">Item three</li> [selected]
        <ul id="ul-level-two">
            <li id="1">Item A</li>
                <ul id="ul-level-three">
                    <li id="1">Item one</li>
                    <li id="2">Item two</li>
                    <li id="3">Item three</li> -- these items fall below page bottom
                    <li id="4">Item four</li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
    <li id="4">Item four</li>
    <li id="5">Item five</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to find a way to ensure that all the items of the ul are displayed.  I tried scrolling the final LI of the most current UL into view, but it does not seem to be working.

```
$('#ul-level-three li:last').get(0).scrollIntoView();
```

Please assist.

KMT

Comment: "*it does not seem to be working.*". How?

Comment: half the list still remains off the bottom of the page--in other words, the final item of the UL is not in view.